# How can redirect domain to ip adress on plesk

Tags: nginx, redirect, dns, plesk

I have a plesk dashbord and i run node js server from ssh and runing with success I can to acccess to this server with [ipAdress]:2000 and i want to add domain on plesk and this domain redirect to this [ipAdress]:2000 but not working

Comment: Do you mean that `https` scheme is working, but `http` is not?

Comment: No I have a plesk dashbord and i run node js server  from ssh and runing with success I can to acccess to this server with [ipAdress]:2000 and i want to add domain on plesk and this domain redirect to this ip but not working

Comment: You definately need to show here your nginx config files to be able to understand what is the exact problem

Answer (score 0):

Hiho.

I think what you are searching for is a so called ReverseProxy.
Take a request on a domain and passthrough the request to a backend server with optioal port.

For Plesk in example i´ve running some dockerized applications which i passthrough with the following additional apache rules:

```
ProxyRequests Off
<Location "/">
    ProxyPass "http://[IP]:[PORT]/"
    ProxyPassReverse "http://[IP]:[PORT]/"
</Location>
```

You can edit those additonal configs in your plesk domain under:
Your Domain -> Hosting and DNS -> Additional settings for apache and nginx

Put it in both fields for additional apache configurations (http & https)

**OR BETTER**

Create a redirect from http to https and put the ProxyPass stuff only in the https field

http:

```
Redirect permanent / https://[YOUR-DOMAIN]/
```

https:

```
ProxyRequests Off
<Location "/">
    ProxyPass "http://[IP]:[PORT]/"
    ProxyPassReverse "http://[IP]:[PORT]/"
</Location>
```